# Asynchronous reads in usb accessory mode

Tags: android, android-usb

In Android, is it possible to do asynchronous reads when communicating with a peripheral using the USB accessory mode?

Comment: What exactly do you need? if you do this reading in a thread it is kind of asyncronous ..

Comment: @ligi: I'd like for the system to call one of my methods when there is data to be read; is there some kind of support for this in the available framework? I could do this myself using a thread, but for it to work properly it would be helpful to be capable of doing **no-blocking** reads or for Google to fix [bug 20545](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=20545).

Comment: I am not aware of any API to do so